# DevicePolicyManager deviceManger.lockNow() is not working anymore after upgrade to Android 4.3

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

My App was working fine before the upgrade on my Samsung Note II, it was able to do lockNow() and wipeData() perfectly using DevicePolicyManager.
i could'nt find any solution to my problem. is there anything i can do to fix it , or google just closed a feature or something?

Answer (score 0):

Both these APIs work OK on vanilla devices. Google has not closed these APIs. This is probably a problem specific to Samsung Note II devices or operator customizations on these devices.

I know for a fact lockNow() and wipeData() work on both 4.3 and 4.4 on other vendor's devices.